# Custom Fill Property on PathGeometry in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties, pathgeometry

I've been looking at (and getting confused by) Dependency Properties - I'm not sure if this is what I need or if there is something else.

I'm looking to something very specific with `<Path.Data/>` children in Silverlight, in particular `<PathGeometry/>`, `<EllipseGeometry/>`, etc. While the `<Path/>` element has a `.Fill` property, I'd like to add a `.Fill` property to any of it's Geometries, meaning it's a different color from it's parent. It could be a `<SolidColorBrush/>` or `<LinearGradientBrush/>` color, or a percentage of the parent color (like 20% darker than `<Path.Fill/>`.

Is this possible? Is this a dependency property? How would `<RectangleGeometry/>`, for example, know that I am trying to fill it with a color? How would I get started?

(*adding WPF as a tag too as someone who knows WPF may be able to help*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not its not possible, the stroke and fill brush are properties of the `Path` shape.

If you want to draw Rectangle, Ellipse etc shapes with their own independent Stroke and Fill properties you need to use `Rectangle` and `Ellipse` which are `Shape` objects in their own right.